# Java regex, digits, plus, minus, pound sign

Tags: java, regex

I've never dealed with regex before.
What combination should I use for string that contains only digits(0-9), plus(+) and minus(-) signs and also pound signs(#)? Order doesn't matter.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: *I've never dealed with regex before.* -> Now would be a really good time to start :)

Comment: Do you think you'll learn from a ready answer that you'll take and copy-paste it?

Comment: I'll learn it as soon as I have some spare time:)
Now I just need it to solve once-only problem
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple:

```
[0-9+#-]+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dP1eL7/1